# AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'guild_permissions'

Tags: discord.py

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM8zb.png)

Hi Hello I have a question, why did I actually get this error I want to know what he actually says and I would love to get a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please provide atleast some code for context. Secondly, don't post a screenshot of the error, just include it as a codeblock in your post. That being said, my best guess from the limited information is that you need to use `ctx.message.author`. In your error screenshot, it seems you are just using `message.author`.

Answer (score 0):

The `guild_permissions.administrator` is not exists on discord.py and that's why you getting `"User" object has no attribute 'guild_permissions'` error and you do not need to post a screenshot here but it's okay.

Also do you have the `has_permissions`?

If you do not have then

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import is_owner, has_permissions, MissingPermissions, BadArgument
```

If you do, use

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def command(ctx):
        #yourscript
```

> That's just my opinion what i was thinking.

If you're using `on_message` then please provide a script what you did.